# scss join classes

Tags: css, layout, less, sass

So, this is the example of "LESS" code

```
.my_class{
    color: #000;
    font: 12px/12px Arial;
    &_comething_else{ color: #f00; }
}
```

which will be compiled into this:

```
.my_class{
    color: #000;
    font: 12px/12px Arial;
}


.my_class_something_else{
    color: #f00;
}
```

Classes ".my_class" and "_something_else" were joined,
but with SCSS this code will be compiled into this:

```
.my_class{
    color: #000;
    font: 12px/12px Arial;
}


.my_class _something_else{
    color: #f00;
}
```

where is whitespace after ".my_class" before underscore in "_something_else"

So, is there any way to do this LESS  trick in SCSS?
Thanks.

Comment: I think SCSS always assumes a space when the parent selector (&) is joined by something else than a `#` hex or `.` dot. Probably to help people write code that makes sense but they obviously overlooked this use case...

Comment: post it as an answer and accept it as one, since I don't think there is a 'nice' way of doing this.

Comment: Yeah. I had to wait, no enough rating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. It's more uglier than in LESS but works:

```
$ns: ".my_class";
.my_class{
    color: #000;
    font: 12px/12px Arial;
    #{$ns}_comething_else{ color: #f00; }
}
```

will be compiled into

```
.my_class{
    color: #000;
    font: 12px/12px Arial;
}

.my_class .my_class_comething_else{
    color: #f00;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if it's still not possible to join class names in SASS(3.2.6) I noticed that you can do it over at jsFiddle.

Here is the code I've used:

```
.elem {
    &__child {
        border: solid red;

        &-text {
            color: blue;
        }
    }
}
```

Check out the examle http://jsfiddle.net/nicolasmn/6cvFZ/